# In python, how can I get how many groups I get in regular expression

Tags: python

In python, I can use regular expression like this:

```
prog = re.compile(pattern)
result = prog.match(string)
```

And I can result.groups(0), result.groups(0), ... etc.

How can I find out how many groups in the result?  I tried 'len(result.groups)', but I get:

```
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `len(result.groups())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying is correct but you just missed the parentheses:

Try:

```
len(result.groups())
```

That should do the work. As the error suggests, you are trying to get the length of a function. What you want is the length of the value (in this case, a tuple) returned after the execution of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
result.lastindex.
```

See also http://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can call dir(result)/help(result), then you'll find the method you can call. And as other one suggests, groups()

Comment: `dir(result)/help(result)` blew my mind for a second! and then I realized it was not division :)